# ¿Puede un evento generado en una página modificar los valores de inputs hallados en otra?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sigo avanzando en mi aplicación. Si me encuentro en esta página, y hago click en "Alta V.", se limpian todos los inputs correspondientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que independientemente de la página en donde me encuentre, cada vez que haga clic sobre "Alta vacunación", también me limpie los datos. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$("li#altavac a").on("click", function () {
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_exp_vacunacion").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_vacuna").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_codigolote").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_codigovacuna").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lote").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dosistotal").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dosisdisponibles").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fechacaducidad").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_exp_vacunacion").val("");
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_nombre").val(literalesPage[50312]);
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_municipio").val(literalesPage[50312]);
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_calificacionsanitaria").val("");

var data = {
    "explotacion": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_exp_vacunacion").val(),
    "fecha": "",
    "codigovacuna": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_codigovacuna").val(),
    "vacuna": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_vacuna").val(),
    "codigolote": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_codigolote").val(),
    "lote": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lote").val(),
    "denominacion": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_nombre").val(),
    "municipio": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_municipio").val(),
    "calificacionsanitaria": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_calificacionsanitaria").val(),
    "codigocalificacionsanitaria": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_codigocalificacionsanitaria").val(),
    "especie": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_especie").val(),
    "fechacaducidad": "",
    "numunidadesdisponibles": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dosisdisponibles").val(),
    "numunidadestotal": $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dosistotal").val()



};

$.ajax({
    url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname + "/setVacunasAnimales",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
});


})
```

Este código me funciona bien en la página que os he mostrado. Lo que he hecho ha sido copiar y pegar este código en las páginas de la aplicación, y aunque no me produce error, no surte efecto. ¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a Jquery/js que cambie los valores de los inputs que están en una página diferente?

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Estas usando `iframe` ?

Comment: No. No estoy usando iframe. Gracias

Comment: ¿Tienes dos pestañas abiertas en un navegador y quieres que el código de una página afecte otra página abierta en la otra pestaña? ¿las tienes abiertas en navegadores distintos? o ¿qué es exactamente _otra página_? en el contexto en el que hablas. Pregunto porque no me queda nada clara la explicación que das.

Comment: Hola jachguate. Me refiero a que si estoy tanto en la página de inicio, o si me encuentro en selección de crotales (por ejemplo), si desde esas páginas, clico sobre  "Alta vacunación", me limpie los valores. Quiero decir con independencia de si me encuentro en la página "Alta Vacunación". Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es tener una función que limpie todos los campos en el documento, independientemente de cuales sean, puedes utilizar la función que encontrarás más abajo.

Esta función utiliza jQuery (debe ser mayor a 1.6) y básicamente toma todos los inputs, los va filtrando y va limpiando sus propiedades y valores.

También toma todos los _select_s y los *resetea* al primer valor disponible.

Como puedes ver, el código no hace referencia a ningún ID u otro selector específico del formulario o del documento. Como siempre, se requiere de HTML bien formado para un funcionamiento estable y robusto.

```js
function limpiarTodosLosCampos() {
  $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .prop('checked', false)
    .prop('selected', false)
    .not(':checkbox, :radio, select').val('');  
    
  $("select").each(function(index) {
    $(this).val($(`#${this.id} option:first`).val()); 
  });
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="id1">Uno</label><input id="id1" type="text" /><br>
<label for="id2">Dos</label><input id="id2" type="email" /><br>
<label for="id3">Tres</label><input id="id3" type="search" /><br>
<label for="id4">Cuatro</label><input id="id4" type="tel" /><br>
<label for="id5">Cinco</label><input id="id5" type="url" /><br>
<label for="id6">Seis</label><input id="id6" type="number" /><br>
<label for="id7">Siete</label><input id="id7" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50"/><br>
<label for="id8">Ocho</label><input id="id8" type="datetime-local" /><br>
<label for="id9">Nueve</label><input id="id9" type="month" /><br>
<label for="id10">Diez</label><input id="id10" type="time" /><br>
<label for="id11">Once</label><input id="id11" type="week" /><br>
<label for="sel">Select</label>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
  <option value="uno">Uno</option>
  <option value="dos">Dos</option>
  <option value="tres">Tres</option>
  <option value="cuatro">Cuatro</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="sel2">Select2</label>
<select name="sel2" id="sel2">
  <option value="cinco">Cinco</option>
  <option value="seis">Seis</option>
  <option value="siete">Siete</option>
  <option value="ocho">Ocho</option>
</select>
<br>
<p>Radio:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="rd_uno" name="radio" value="uno">
  <label for="rd_uno">uno</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="rd_dos" name="radio" value="dos">
  <label for="rd_dos">dos</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="rd_tres" name="radio" value="tres">
  <label for="rd_tres">tres</label>
<br>
<p>Checkbox:</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck_uno" name="check" value="uno">
  <label for="ck_uno">uno</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck_dos" name="check" value="dos">
  <label for="ck_dos">dos</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck_tres" name="check" value="tres">
  <label for="ck_tres">tres</label>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="limpiarTodosLosCampos()">Limpiar todo</button>
```

El código está en un *snippet* de manera que puedes probarlo aquí mismo en la respuesta haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Answer (score 1):

Si los campos están dentro de un `form` bastaría con llamar a la función `reset` del mismo, por ejemplo para una página con uno o varios formularios solo necesitas hacer:

```
document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(f=>f.reset())
```

Demo:

```js
function reset(){
 //buscamos todos los form y los reseteamos
 document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(f=>f.reset())
}
```

```css
input{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="reset()">Este sería el link que está en el menú, presionar para resetear</a>


<hr>
Un formulario: 
<form>
  <input >
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <input type="radio" >
  <select>
   <option>opción 1</option>
   <option>opcion 2</option>
   </select>
</form>
<br>
<hr>
Otro formulario
<form>
  <input type="date" >
  <select>
   <option>opción 1</option>
   <option>opcion 2</option>
   </select>
</form>
```